# ASP.NET MVC Dynamic Number Type

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, dynamic

I'm running a query in my ASP.NET MVC3 application to get some numbers from the database:

```
var idQuery = "SELECT " + dynamicColumnName + " FROM " + dynamicTableName;
long[] idItems = db.Database.SqlQuery<long>(idQuery).ToArray();
```

However, the dynamic column is sometimes int type `int` and sometimes `long`. I tried `long` as it covers int, but the program thrown the exception:

> The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Int32' type to the 'System.Int64' type is not valid.

I tried the type `dynamic` but couldn't get the numbers right:

```
dynamic[] idItems = db.Database.SqlQuery<dynamic>(idQuery).ToArray();
long[] idItemsLong = new long[idItems.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < idItemsLong.Length; i++)
{
    idItemsLong[i] = Convert.ToInt64(idItemsLong[i]);
}
```

Throws the exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

What can I do to work my query run for both `int`s and `long`s? Ways of getting the dynamic type and converting them to long work for me, I can use the idItems as long in my following lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution working without dynamic types:

```
long[] idItems = new long[1];
long[] valueItems = new long[1];

try
{
    idItems = db.Database.SqlQuery<long>(idQuery).ToArray();
    valueItems = db.Database.SqlQuery<long>(valueQuery).ToArray();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    int[] idItemsInt = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(idQuery).ToArray();
    int[] valueItemsInt = db.Database.SqlQuery<int>(valueQuery).ToArray();
    idItems = new long[idItemsInt.Length];
    valueItems = new long[idItemsInt.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < idItems.Length; i++)
    {
        idItems[i] = Convert.ToInt64(idItemsInt[i]);
        valueItems[i] = Convert.ToInt64(valueItemsInt[i]);
    }
}
```

By this I get longs first, if type is int, than I get ints and convert them to long. If I had a dynamic type, I would always do conversion. So if my type is long (generally is), I am free of unnecessary conversion and I think this is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try plain old `object`:

```
object[] idItems = db.Database.SqlQuery<object>(idQuery).ToArray();
long[] idItemsLong = new long[idItems.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < idItemsLong.Length; i++)
{
    idItemsLong[i] = Convert.ToInt64(idItems[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thrown the exception: 

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: Please try before you're posting an answer first.